# To evaluate a monotonic function over a convex set, does it suffice to consider the vertices?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Given function $f : P \to \mathbb R$, where $P \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a convex polytope, I want to find the minimum and maximum of $f$ provided that $x \in P$.

I can show that $f$ is monotonic over the set $P$, i.e., the elements of the gradient do not change their signs. For the case that $P$ is an interval, I can evaluate $f$ at the vertices of this interval to find the minimum and maximum. Is the same true if $P$ is a convex polytope?

Comment: If the definition of monotonic is that the components of the gradient do not change sign on $P$ then the answer is no. Take $f(x) = 3x_1 + \sin x_1 - 2 x_2 - \cos x_2 - x_3$, and take $P$ to be he polytope joining the origin to some suitable point such as $(10,10,10)$. Then $f$ has local $\min,\max$ on the relative interior of $P$.

Comment: It seems to me that is this example, the elements of the gradient change multiple times within the polytope: e.g. the derivative of sin x_1 is cos x_1, which varies between -1 and 1 over the line between the origin and (10,10,10)

Comment: The three elements of the gradient of $f$ do not change sign on the given $P$.